# How to display bash special characters \h, \s, etc

Tags: linux, bash

I can't find a way to display bash special chars. For example the hostname is \h.
If I do :

```
echo '\h \\h'
```

it won't work ( display h \h). How can I make it display my hostname ?

ref : http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html

Answer (score 0):

Those are only evaluated in the PS1 and PS2 variables. You can test them dynamically like this:

```
PS1="\h"
```

The bash will then display the new prompt. Just open a new bash if you mess it up, it will not be saved.

Answer (score 0):

The HOWTO told you it is "Prompt Escape Sequences", only works when you put then in PS1 or PS2,